# UITapGestureRecognizer not triggering on UIImageView created programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, xcode4.5, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm using XCode 4.5.1 .

I added `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` in .h file and in the start of .m file

```
@interface FirstViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *img1;

@end
```

Then in `viewDidLoad`, creating `UIImageView` programmatically like

```
self.img1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, -30, 44, 44)];
[self.img1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]];
[self.img1 setAlpha:0.8];
[self.img1 setHidden:NO];
[self.img1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.img1 setTag:901];
```

And then

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(guessTapObject:)];
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
tap.delegate = self;

[self.img1 addGestureRecognizer:tap];

[self.view addSubview:self.img1];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.img1];
```

and at the end

```
- (void)guessTapObject:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) gesture
{
    // guessing the image
    UIImageView *tapImageView = (UIImageView*) gesture.view;
    NSLog(@"Gesture Tag: %d", tapImageView.tag);
}
```

I have 4 different images and creating them programmatically as described above. And applying the animation to move them from top to bottom.

I want that when user tap on the image, it should animate and disappear(i know that code). But  the code is not triggering the tap event. I put the breakpoint on the start of the `guessTapObject` function, but don't go there ever.

At `UITapGestureRecognizer` declaration, debugging shows that `guessTapObject` is attached to the recognizer to perform the tap action.

Please help why tap event is not triggering its selector method???

Thanks for your help in advance.

---

Edited:
i also tried with for loop to have gesture recognizer separately for every imageview

```
for (UIView * view in self.view.subviews) {
    if (view.tag > 900){
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(guessTapObject:)];
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    //    tap.delegate = self;
        [view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        NSLog(@"tapView: %@", tap.view);
        NSLog(@"tap: %i", tap.enabled);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the code you posted and it is working fine for me. I am getting callback. If you are using multiple images you need to create different UITapGestureRecognizer too. For one image the code should work fine please check whether anything is nil or your generation code is not getting called or something.

Comment: This is working, Make sure which image you are tapping as you set it's y cord to -30, check that.

Comment: @amit3117.... i tried using for loop, too to add separate gesturerecognizer for each image, but doesn't work at my end.

Comment: @unbounded show your for loop code.

Comment: @Navnath.... as i'm animating my image so it is moving and will be displayed as animation starts (animation is working). Ok, i show you the for loop code, too.

i also tried by commenting `tap.delegate = self;` this line. but it also didn't solved the problem.

Comment: @unbounded is your loop print logs ?

Comment: @unbounded... I tried this and it work for me, i added 3 images to my view & it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved by applying gesture on view, instead of each image view separately.

`[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];`

and then in handler/selector `guessTapObject` function, i used this

```
CGPoint tapLocation = [gesture locationInView:self.view]; // gives the tap coordinates
for (UIView * view in self.view.subviews) { // gives view by iterating on each subview
    CGRect dropRect = [[[view layer] presentationLayer] frame]; // specific way of getting the frame with respect to its layer

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(dropRect, tapLocation)){ // checks for tap in the boundaries of view frame
        if (view.tag > 900) // my specific view
             // done what i want to do with that specific one
             // as i removed it from my superview
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I was stuck in similar issue.. Make sure imageView is set true for userInteraction..

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

It worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

**Check this**
Add following code to your View Controller

- **In viewController.h file**

  ```
  @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *img1;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *img2;
  @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *img3;
  ```
- **In viewController.m file**
  Inside viewDidLoad Method

  ```
  // Init Image 1 
  self.img1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 30, 44, 44)];
  [self.img1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1_name.jpg"]];
  [self.img1 setAlpha:0.8];
  [self.img1 setHidden:NO];
  [self.img1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
  [self.img1 setTag:901];

  // Init Image 2
  self.img2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 30, 44, 44)];
  [self.img2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2_name.jpg"]];
  [self.img2 setAlpha:0.8];
  [self.img2 setHidden:NO];
  [self.img2 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
  [self.img2 setTag:902];

  // Init Image 3
  self.img3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 130, 44, 44)];
  [self.img3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image3_name.jpg"]];
  [self.img3 setAlpha:0.8];
  [self.img3 setHidden:NO];
  [self.img3 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
  [self.img3 setTag:903];

  // Add Images to view
  [self.view addSubview:self.img1];
  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.img1];

  [self.view addSubview:self.img2];
  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.img2];

  [self.view addSubview:self.img3];
  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.img3];

  // Set Tap Gesture to each image of view
  for (UIView * view in self.view.subviews) {
    if (view.tag > 900){
       UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                        initWithTarget:self 
                                        action:@selector(guessTapObject:)];
       tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
       tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
       [view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
       NSLog(@"tapView: %@", tap.view);
       NSLog(@"tap: %i", tap.enabled);
    }
  }
  ```

**Make sure images should be added before for loop(adding TapGesture using array of subview)**